# How to make an image slider using JavaScript with user generated images?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project which:

1. Asks the user to choose images from their device
2. The selected images would show up in the image slider

```js
 const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    
    // load user chosen files 
    fileInp.addEventListener('input', (e) => 
    {
      const files = e.target.files;
      
      for (let file of files) {
        const img = new Image();
        const reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => 
        {
          img.src = e.target.result;
          slider.appendChild(img);
          img.classList.add('slide');
        })
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } 
    })
    
    
    // slider
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    let counter = 0;
    
    slides.forEach((slide, index) => 
    {
      slide.style.left = 
        `${index * 100}%`
    })
    
    nextBtn.onclick = () => {
      counter++;
      move();
    }
    
    prevBtn.onclick = () => {
      counter--;
      move();
    }
    
    function move() {
      if (counter <= 0) {
        counter = slides.length - 1;
      }
      
      if (counter === slides.length) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      
      slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
      slide.style.transform = 
        `translateX(-${counter * 100}%)`
      })
    }
```

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;900");
    
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
      }
    
    body {
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .box {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 1rem;
      gap: 1rem;
    }
    
    .slider {
      min-width: 300px;
      min-height: 70px;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .slide {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
      transition: transform 250ms ease;
    }
    
      h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
      }
    
      .controls {
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.5rem;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
      }
    
      .btn {
        background-color: #333;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0.5rem 0.75em;
        width: 12ch;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px; 
        color: #fff;
      }
    
      .ph {
        background-color: #08b;
        width: max-content;
      }
    
      .btn:hover {
        border: 2px solid #000; 
        border-radius: .25rem;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>

    <div class="slider"></div>

    <div class="controls">
      <button class="btn" id="prevBtn">previous</button>

      <input hidden type="file" id="fileInp" multiple />
      
      <!-- Just a placeholder to easily style the file input -->
      <button onclick="fileInp.click()" class="ph btn">choose files</button>

      <button class="btn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i am adding a snippet so you can understand it clearly,

When using static HTML  tags, the slider works properly but when I generate images from file input using JavaScript it gives unwanted results. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it because on page load `const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');` is empty, move it to file `load` event

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let slides = [];
// load user chosen files 
fileInp.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const files = e.target.files;

  for (let file of files) {
    const img = new Image();
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
      img.src = e.target.result;
      slider.appendChild(img);
      img.classList.add('slide');
      slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
      slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
        slide.style.left =
          `${index * 100}%`
      })
    })

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
})


// slider

let counter = 0;



nextBtn.onclick = () => {
  counter++;
  move();
}

prevBtn.onclick = () => {
  counter--;
  move();
}

function move() {
  if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = slides.length - 1;
  }

  if (counter === slides.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

  slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.style.transform =
      `translateX(-${counter * 100}%)`
  })
}
```

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 110px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  transition: transform 250ms ease;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75em;
  width: 12ch;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
}

.ph {
  background-color: #08b;
  width: max-content;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>

  <div class="slider"></div>

  <div class="controls">
    <button class="btn" id="prevBtn">previous</button>
    <input hidden type="file" id="fileInp" multiple />
    <!-- Just a placeholder to easily style the file input -->
    <button onclick="fileInp.click()" class="ph btn">choose files</button>
    <button class="btn" id="nextBtn">next</button>
  </div>
```